# Contact and collision bitmask not made

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, collision-detection, collision

I've been trying to make contact between two nodes in the simulator they make contact but there's no contact detection. I've tried many methods none of them work. Here is the code

```
var location = CGPoint( x :0 ,y : 0)
class GameScene: SKScene , SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

      override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector.init(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)
        addcircle ()
        addobst () 
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    }

    func addcircle () {
        let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100)

        circle.fillColor = UIColor.red
        circle.name = " CIRCLE "

        circle.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        circle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = contactcategory.circle.rawValue
        circle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = contactcategory.obstacle.rawValue
       circle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = contactcategory.obstacle.rawValue

        circle.position = location
        circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(circleOfRadius: 100)

        addChild(circle)
    }

    func addobst () {
        let A = Double(arc4random_uniform(70))

        let obstacle = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.white, size : CGSize(width: A, height : A))

        obstacle.name = "OBSTACLE"
        obstacle.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        obstacle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = contactcategory.obstacle.rawValue
        obstacle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = contactcategory.circle.rawValue
        obstacle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = contactcategory.circle.rawValue

        let randomx = Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.size.width)))
        if randomx >= Double((self.size.width)/2) {
            obstacle.position = CGPoint( x : randomx - A ,y : Double(self.size.height) + A)
        } else if randomx <= Double((self.size.width)/2) {
            obstacle.position = CGPoint( x : randomx + A ,y : Double(self.size.height) + A)
        }
        obstacle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf: obstacle.size)

        var actionArray = [SKAction]()
        actionArray.append(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint( x : obstacle.position.x ,y : -obstacle.size.height ), duration:3 ))
        actionArray.append(SKAction.removeFromParent())
        obstacle.run(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))
        addChild(obstacle)

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        let contactmask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask
        let contactmask1 = contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

        if ((contactmask == contactcategory.obstacle.rawValue) && ( contactmask1 == contactcategory.circle.rawValue )) {
            print("contact made")
        } else if ((contactmask == contactcategory.circle.rawValue) && ( contactmask1 == contactcategory.obstacle.rawValue )) {
            print("contact made")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `didBegin(_contact:)` called? If yes, could you add an `else` and print the two values?

Comment: i didn't understand about adding an else

Comment: In `func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)`, add `print("didBegin(_contact:)")`. At the end print `contactmask` and `contactmask1`.

Comment: it didn't work thank you anyway